# Checking what 'DROP' queries were ran on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-drop

Some one keeps dropping tables on one of our database's as soon as I gain access the server. I don't know who this some one is. I have nearly lost my job once because of this person.

So I was wondering is there a way I can check which user ran a query for `DROP TABLE my_table` so that I can prove to my boss I am innocent?

Comment: @Barry I know it's an odd question, but I don't think deleting all the background information helps.

Comment: @Tim - I don't think all the background info adds any value to what is actually an interesting question. It's generally the sort of blurb that encourages a question to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On SQL Server 2005 or newer, you could also investigate [DDL triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190989%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) which would even allow you to prohibit certain `DROP TABLE` statements....

```
CREATE TRIGGER safety 
ON DATABASE 
FOR DROP_TABLE
AS 
   PRINT 'You must disable Trigger "safety" to drop tables!' 
   ROLLBACK
;
```

This would basically just prevent anyone from dropping a table

Comment: Combine this with an insert into a log table and you could both protect the table from being dropped and gather evidence of who/when it was attempted